# Multiple files not uploading in play framework

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework-2.5

I wanted to upload multiple files simultaneously. But only one file which is first in the uploading list is being uploaded instead of all the selected files.

My code is as shown below,

```
public Result multiUpload(){
MultipartFormData md=request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        List<FilePart> file = md.getFiles();;

        for(FilePart p: file){
            String fileName = p.getFilename();
             File newFile = (File) p.getFile();
              String myUploadPath = Play.application().configuration().getString("myUploadPath");
              newFile.renameTo(new File(myUploadPath, fileName));

                return ok("file saved as " + myUploadPath +" "+ fileName);
          }
        return ok("uploaded");

    }
```

can anyone help on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

```
List<FilePart<Object>> fileParts = request().body().asMultipartFormData().getFiles();
        for(FilePart filePart : fileParts) {
           filePart.getFile();
           String myUploadPath = Play.application().configuration().getString("myUploadPath");
           ((File) filePart.getFile()).renameTo(new File(myUploadPath, filePart.getFilename()));
        }
```

This is uploading 3 files at a time. Now am trying for solution to upload more than 3 files simultaneously.